# Converting raw data to graph ready data

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, graph

I am sure there is a simple solution to this, but I have come up empty in my search so far.

What I have is pulling in an array of director's name, and found a nice clean for loop to count the given directors and provide the total for each.

```
let countDirectors = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < directorsArray.length; i++) {
    countDirectors[directorsArray[i]] = 1 + (countDirectors[directorsArray[i]] || 0);}
```

But what I haven't been unable to figure out is how to then alter this to get it graphable.

The graph I am using requires the data to be displayed like such.

```
{x: "Director Name1", y: 2}, {x: "DirectorName2", y: 4}
```

What would be the best way to alter my original for loop to have the object setup like the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you exactly receive the names array, and I assumed the output supposed to be an array of object.
So for this input: `['name1', 'name2', 'name2', 'name2', 'name1']` I applied this logic:
```
    const names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name2', 'name2', 'name1'];

```
const graphable = names.reduce((forGraph, name) => {
const current = forGraph.find(item => item.x === name);
if (current) {
    current.y +=1
} else {
    forGraph.push({
        x: name,
        y: 1
    })
}
    return forGraph
}, []);
```

This logic can be simplified of course, but it's written this is way so it easier for you to understand

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
const countDirectors = new Map([...new Set(directorsArray)].map(
    x => [x, directorsArray.filter(y => y === x).length])
);
```

These are new ES6 features. `Set` looks at all unique values and stores them in an array with the help of the spread operator. This is then passed into Map that creates an iterable object.

Edit:
You can iterate over `countDirectors` with for example
`countDirectors.forEach((key, value) => {x: ${key}, y: ${value}})`
or similar to get it in the format you need for the graphing.